# XSLT 1.0 get distinct values fails

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, distinct

I need some help with a problem in my xslt code.
Used processor/debugger & IDE: MSXML 6.0 in MS Visual Studio 2012.

My exact input (teared down just to the elements i need for my selection.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <components>
    <Object3D id="130" plName="STF45668"/>
    <Object3D id="131" plName="RIOD122"/>
    <Object3D id="132" plName="RIOD122"/>
    <Object3D id="133" plName="RIOD122"/>
    <Object3D id="182" plName="RIOD124"/>
    <Object3D id="183" plName="RIOD124"/>
    <Object3D id="184" plName="RIOD124"/>
    <Object3D id="185" plName="RIOD124"/>
  </components>
</root>
```

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <xsl:key name ="objectsByName" use="/root/components/Object3D" match="@plName"/>
  <xsl:output media-type="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="allObjs" select="//Object3D"/>
    <xsl:variable name="distinctObjsCount" 
                  select="//Object3D[count(. | key('objectsByName', @plName)[1]) = 1]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="distinctObjsGenID" 
                  select="//Object3D[generate-id() = 
                          generate-id(key('objectsByName', @plName)[1])]"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="//Object3D[count(. | key('objectsByName', @plName)[1]) = 1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(@plName, '(',count(key('objectsByName', @plName)),')')"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the transformation output i get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
STF45668(0), RIOD122(0), RIOD122(0), RIOD122(0), RIOD124(0), RIOD124(0), RIOD124(0), RIOD124(0)
```

But I fail in getting the distinct values from those Object3D elements.

So... I have no idea why this goes wrong.
Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

edit: now 1:1 to the files I am using.

Comment: Please show a full XSLT stylesheet so that we can reproduce your issue. Also, a complete XML input would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you really want that. The real input file has about 5k lines of program generated XML code, the xsl file has about 4k lines, too. That's because I'm creating .odt file from premade templates --> huge overhead. What I can do is adding all attributes that are relevant for the affected elements.

Comment: I did not ask for a 10k dump of everything you have. But if you want people to track down an error/inconsistency/surprising result you really a) have to post everything or b) isolate this problem in a small subset of your input and code. Otherwise, all bets are off.

Comment: Re your added input: there's nothing one can do with it, except stare at it. The smart thing to do is post code that can be copied, pasted and run to reproduce the issue. Then you may get some answers.

Comment: Sorry for that. Bad day, no coffee x). I made a much smaller test area for that which matches 1:1 the code i used and processed.

Comment: You key element is "upside down": it needs to have `match="Object3D" use="@plName"` not the other way around.  -- BTW, there's no need to specify the path leading to the matched node, unless you have other nodes with the same name elsewhere in your input.

Comment: Oh my god! I'm so sorry! x) That was it. It works like it should now. I didn't see that all the time. I'm so embarassed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input doesn't look right to me. A proper input XML would be something like:

```
<root>
<components>
    <Object3D plName="chair" />
    <Object3D plName="cup" />
    <Object3D plName="desk" />
    <Object3D plName="cup" />
    <Object3D plName="chair" />
    <Object3D plName="chair" />
    <Object3D plName="desk" />
    <Object3D plName="cup" />
</components>
</root>
```

And, following XSLT should work fine with this XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:key name="Object" match="Object3D" use="@plName"/>

<xsl:template match="/root/components">
    <xsl:for-each select="Object3D[count(. | key('Object', @plName)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@plName, '(',count(key('Object', @plName)),')')"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The keys are used to group the Object3D, and inside the for-each, forming the output you want:

```
chair(3), cup(3), desk(2)
```

Comment: That is the funny part of my problem.
This selection results in returning ALL Object3D elements of the input file.
The grouping doesn't work as it should.

The output of the code above is the following:
chair(0), chair(0), chair(0), cup(0), cup(0), cup(0), desk(0), desk(0)

Trust me, I am surprised of the result, too.

Comment: @steven.eisenreich No, that's not true - at least with Saxon it works exactly as described. What processor are you working with?

Comment: I work with MS Visual Studio 2012. So the used processor should me the MSXML 6.0 processor, as far as I know.

Comment: But i agree with you that the shown xml SHOULD produce the output that is shown above by Lingamurthy CS.
I begin to believe that this is an MSXML bug.

Comment: @steven.eisenreich Check (and double-check) your implementation. This is strictly by-the-book [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html); if it weren't working in one of the major XSLT processors, I think the word would be out by now.